# Lucene simulation for ElasticSearch queries - the NOT clause

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm building a pure lucene-based implementation for legacy system that should locally (in-process) run arbitrary (more or less) queries. I receive queries in textual form, like `term1:A OR term2:B`. My default operator for queries is `AND`. For compatibility reasons I'm using lucene 5.5. I'm basing the solution on `MemoryIndex` single-document implementation.
My main problem is with how lucene deals with `NOT` clause: in query of sort
`termA:(NOT 0) term2:(xxx)` lucene would produce the following query:
`+(-termA:0) +term2:xxx`. While logically pretty sound, in practice this query shall always produce nothing since the negate-only clause always returns no_docs response and `AND` with it shall always produce empty result. The only workaround that I found (here on SOF) for this is to inject a `MatchAllDocs` clause together with the negative clause, like `termA:(*:* NOT 0)`, but this is an error prone approach since it involves intricate clause parsing - the `MatchAllDocs` should only be injected if there are no `positive` clauses inside the parenthesis.

I'm looking for a more robust/generic approach to this problem, preferable some library that can parse/handle it for me, maybe something in `contrib` or similar.